# Reinitializing Java Class

Tags: java, static, initialization, jvmti

We are working on a JVMTI Java Agent, that is used to instrument java class files. A small part of it is (obviously) native c++ code, but the larger part is Java code, which is loaded over the network and called from the native agent code.
We use a code coverage tool to collect test coverage for the java part, which does source code instrumentation.

Now when our agent starts, some classes get initialized, specifically java.lang.ref.Reference, which starts a Thread. Our Agent instruments the Thread start method with custom java code, which is instrumented by the code coverage tool.
The coverage tool puts some static inner classes with static initializers in our java agent code, so this gets executed as a consequence of java.lang.ref.Reference getting initialized.

The Problem is, that at this time (when java.lang.ref.Reference gets initialized), some basic functionality of the JVM is not in place yet. Specifically, the code coverage tools initializer wants to access System.getProperty(String name), but System.props is still null, so the call results in a NullPointerException. 
This leads to the static inner class of the code coverage tool is being left uninitialized, the class is in state initialization_error, the result is NoClassDefFoundError. Each follow up access to this class results in a NoClassDefFoundError.

My intention now is to ignore this initial initialization error, and wait until VM_Start and then reset the ClassState of the class in question to "linked". This way i hope that the JVM will try to initialize the class again in follow up accesses to the class.

Does anyone have an idea, if this can be done from the JVMTI Agent, and give me some suggestions how this could be done?

Answer (score 0):

From your description, I get the feeling that your code is too tightly coupled. What you really want is to have an initialized Java VM *before* you start your tests.

So instead of messing with native code and an agent, I suggest to split the code into three classes:

- The Java code in an abstract base class
- A class which extends the base class and implements the abstract methods with the native C++ code. Ideally, this class should not contain any Java code except for native method declarations.
- A mockup class for tests which defines the same methods with empty bodies (or ones that just return `null`).

For the tests, instantiate the mock-up class. Override the methods that you need for the test so you can return mock data objects which the code under test needs (see [mockito](http://mockito.org/) for some example about mock-up testing)

Alternatively, test the Java loading code in a test case. In all other tests, add the class to your classpath and just instantiate it as usual.

Comment: We are in an integrationtest scenario here, i.e. we do want to test our instrumentation and the instrumented code in a "real-world" situation and not in a mock-up. As i stated in a previous comment, the only problem is the code coverage tool, which comes into the game too early. Since this tool is not under our control and is closed source, i do not have the possibility to change anything there.

Comment: PS: Yes, you are right, the native code IS tightly coupled to the VM, but thats what this is exactly what we want: We need to go as deep as possible to find out anything that happens within the VM. This is not any end-user application, this is a very technical analysis tool.

Answer (score 0):

A RetransformClasses after VM_Start will generate a new class load hook for Reference allowing you to do your instrumentation in a safe VM phase... Either just Retransform Reference or getLoadedClasses and Retransform them all.

Comment: Do i understand correctly: You suggest to do our instrumentation at a later point. For various reasons, this is not possible. I am afraid i can not go into details here, since i simply do not know them but my colleague assured that the instrumentation has to happen as early as possible. Basically we **DO WANT** this behaviour in our agent, but the situation with the code coverage's source implementation is a special case that makes problems. Usually, the only code that is executed at that time is from the jdk, and this code is aware of the early state.

Comment: You're going to have a lot of difficulty instrumenting and calling your own java in the primordial phase of the JVM, especially on the the Sun JVM. My profiler is all in C and it waits until JVM_Start then switches on profiling with a static boolean. The dependency and circularity problems during primordial are significant. Are you really interested in the early Java methods run in this phase?this